# Using a window function to get a max value over multiple records - SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, window-functions

I am still new to SQL and I am having trouble getting a maximum value over multiple records in SQL. I would normally use a view and join the view to my stored procedure but I need to be able to do this without views because of dynamic table names.

Here is my code:

```
SELECT     rcl.CaseCaseId AS CaseId, cc.Label AS CaseName, rpt.RptDateCum, cp.Label, rpt.CorpProductId, corp.Label AS Scenario, proj.Label AS Project, 
                      ProjectScenario.ReportDate
into #CumTemp
FROM         PhdRpt.ReportCaseList_542 AS rcl INNER JOIN
                      CaseScenario AS cs ON rcl.CaseCaseId = cs.CaseCaseId INNER JOIN
                      CorpScenario AS corp ON cs.CorpScenarioId = corp.CorpScenarioId INNER JOIN
                      CaseCases AS cc ON cs.CaseCaseId = cc.CaseCaseId INNER JOIN
                      PhdRpt.RptProductTech_542 AS rpt ON rcl.ReportId = rpt.ReportID AND rcl.ReportRunCaseId = rpt.RptCaseId INNER JOIN
                      CorpProduct AS cp ON rpt.CorpProductId = cp.CorpProductId INNER JOIN
                      ProjProject AS proj ON cs.ProjProjectId = proj.ProjProjectId INNER JOIN
                      ProjectScenario ON cs.ProjProjectId = ProjectScenario.ProjProjectId AND cs.CorpScenarioId = ProjectScenario.CorpScenarioId AND 
                      corp.CorpScenarioId = ProjectScenario.CorpScenarioId AND proj.ProjProjectId = ProjectScenario.ProjProjectId AND 
                      proj.ProjProjectId = ProjectScenario.ProjProjectId
WHERE     (cs.CorpScenarioId = 1) AND (cs.Deleted = 0)
ORDER BY CaseId


Select  ROW_NUMBER() OVER(order by caseid) as Row, CaseId, Scenario,Project, ReportDate, ltrim(str(sum(Gas))) as Gas, ltrim(str(SUM(Oil))) as Oil, ltrim(str(SUM(Water))) as Water
,MAX(oil) over (partition by Project) as oilmax, MAX(gas) over (partition by Project) as gasmax, MAX(water) over (partition by Project) as watermax
from #CumTemp
pivot (max (RptDateCum) for Label in ([Gas], [Oil], [Water]))as x
group by CaseId, Scenario,Project, ReportDate, Oil
order by Row 
drop table #CumTemp
```

What I am trying to accomplish is to compare the records and find the max value of Gas, Oil, and Water, and create 3 new columns that will have those values in it. The reason I do not want to use a group by is because I still need to access each individual record. All records belong to the same project.

My desired output would look something like this.

```
id      oil    gas    water   oilmax    gasmax    watermax   
----------------------------------------------------------
 1       25     12       6      51        98         37
 2       36     98      19      51        98         37
 3       51     19      22      51        98         37
 4       45     77      37      51        98         37
 5       22     64      31      51        98         37
```

When I use my code it is giving me multiple rows per record when I only want one row per record. Is there another way of accomplishing this without using views or windowfunctions?

Comment: you just need the max value of those tree columns ? try something like `select * from (yourquery), (select max(oil) as oilmax, max(gas), max(water) from (yourquery) ) where someconditions`

Comment: I shuddered when I read the sentence "...I need to be able to do this without views because of dynamic table names."

Comment: @RolandP - You don't mention the dynamic element of your query anywhere else in the question so take my comment with a pinch of salt and a smile :) Generally, I avoid the use of dynamic SQL (over using a `view`) so the server can save an execution plan; which can result in faster execution and also make code maintenance easier because everything you need to know is in the query. I'm interested to know why, and how, you are using dynamic table names.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, as your query is very large I will show how to solve your problem and you put it in your query. This is my test case:

Table

```
create table testcase(
    id integer,
    oil integer,
    gas integer,
    water integer
);
```

Inserts

```
insert into testcase values ( 1, 25, 12,  6 );
insert into testcase values ( 2, 36, 98, 19);
insert into testcase values ( 3, 51, 19,  22);
insert into testcase values ( 4, 45, 77,  37);
insert into testcase values ( 5, 22, 64,  31);
```

Sql

```
select * 
  from testcase as test,
       (select max(oil) maxoil, 
               max(gas) maxgas, 
               max(water) maxwater 
          from testcase) as maxes 
 order by test.id
```

This should give you your data as you want.
Look at fiddle http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/be2b7/3/0

Comment: Does the nested select statement come before or after the pivot? I cannot get it to work either way. The oil, gas, and water values are all coming from one column to begin with.

Comment: I get the following error `Msg 116, Level 16, State 1, Line 14
Only one expression can be specified in the select list when the subquery is not introduced with EXISTS.`

Comment: `Select  ROW_NUMBER() OVER(order by caseid) as Row, CaseId, CaseName, ltrim(str(sum(Gas))) as Gas, ltrim(str(SUM(Oil))) as Oil, ltrim(str(SUM(Water))) as Water
,(select max(oil) maxoil, 
               max(gas) maxgas, 
               max(water) maxwater 
          from #CumTemp) as maxes
from #CumTemp
pivot (max (RptDateCum) for Label in ([Gas], [Oil], [Water]))as x
group by CaseId, CaseName
order by Row 
drop table #CumTemp`

Comment: I was finally able to solve this by storing the pivot into a global temp table and then using your technique. Thank you @Jorge Campos